# Perl Archive::Zip weird response

Tags: zip, perl

This has really baffled me: This code works fine ...

```
$filename="name_of_file.pdf";

for ($x=0; $x<@pdf; $x++){
$file.=$pdf[$x];
}
$file=~s/\*ref\*/$new_aff/g;    # converts a variable within the PDF

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new(); 
$now=time();
$save_zip=$now.".zip";
my $member = $zip->addString($file,$filename);
$member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_DEFLATED );
$member->desiredCompressionLevel( 9 );
die 'write error' unless $zip->writeToFileNamed($save_zip) == AZ_OK;

open (FILE, "<$save_zip");
flock(FILE,2);
binmode(FILE);
    while(<FILE>){
    $infile.=$_;
    }
flock(FILE,8);
close (FILE);

unlink($save_zip);
$filename=~s/\.pdf/\.zip/;


print "Content-type: application/zip\n";
print "Content-disposition: inline;filename=\"$filename\"\n\n";
print $infile;
```

The file is read in, and stored in @pdf. It is then converted to a file rather than array. It's then added to a zip and saved out. It's then read in again to print out to screen to open the save dialogue. (OK, so coding is a little "iffy", but saves messing about with streams etc which I know nowt about!)

Now I'm doing virtually the same thing, but instead of a single filename, I'm reading a directory, and then making calls to a sub routine ...

```
opendir(PDF, "../data/viral/");
@pdfDir=readdir(PDF);
closedir(DIR);
@pdfDir=grep(!/^\./, @pdfDir);
@pdfDir=grep(!/\.txt/, @pdfDir);

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new(); 
$now=time();
$save_zip=$now.".zip";

for ($x=0; $x<@pdfDir; $x++){
 &process_all;
 }
die 'write error' unless $zip->writeToFileNamed($save_zip) == AZ_OK;  # Write file out once loop finished

sub process_all{    # Processs all the PDF's
&open_pdf;          # Read in as BINMODE
    for ($z=0; $z<@pdf; $z++){
    $file.=$pdf[$z];
    }
$file=~s/\*ref\*/$new_aff/g;    # converts a variable within the PDF

my $member = $zip->addString($file,$pdfDir[$x]);
$member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_DEFLATED );
$member->desiredCompressionLevel( 9 );
$file="";   # Empty the file ready for next PDF
}
```

But it complains that it "Can't call method "addString" on an undefined value" And yet filename is showing as being correct, and the pdf is being converted to a file as shown if I do a print to screen.

I tried $filename=$pdf[$x] within $x loop, and in the sub routine. Both show the correct filename, but neither avoid the error.

It's probably staring me in the face - but I can't see it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

At the top of the code where I opened the directory, I used "opendir(PDF..." but on the closedir I had "closedir(DIR ..." which meant that the stream was still open. Then - when I went to open the file, I used "open(PDF ..." and that was already open, so it was unable to read in the data to store in the zip.

Or at least, that was part of problem. It still didn't seem to like running from a sub routine! In the end, I had to use:

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
$zip = Archive::Zip->new(); 
$now=time();
$save_zip=$now.".zip";

for ($x=0; $x<@pdfDir; $x++){
$filename=$pdfDir[$x];
&open_pdf;
$file=~s/\*ref\*/$new_aff/g;
$member = $zip->addString($file,$filename);
$member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_DEFLATED );
$member->desiredCompressionLevel( 9 );
$file="";
}
die 'write error' unless $zip->writeToFileNamed($save_zip) == AZ_OK;
```

And the open routine is now:

```
open (PDF, "<....$filename");
while(<PDF>){
$file.=$_;
}
close(PDF);
```

This might help someone who gets similarly odd results!